# How to enable TLS 1.1/1.2 for Amazon Simple Email Service

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I have been successfully sending EMail using the Amazon-SES for years. However, for PCI compliance reasons, we have been attempting to disable TLS 1.0:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

However, this causes exceptions when trying to send EMail:

```
AuthenticationException:
    A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
    The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not 
    possess a common algorithm
```

As soon as I add SecurityProtocolType.Tls back in, this again succeeds.
Happens both with .NET 4.5 and 4.6.
Using AWSSDK-SimpleEmail (v3.1.1.1) & AWSSDK-Core Runtime (v3.1.2.1)

Comment: Wild stab: what happens if you configure only 1.1 or 1.2, not both?

Comment: Good thought but unfortunately no - only SecurityProtocolType.Tls seems to work.

Comment: I hit the same problem today, caused in my case by upgrading to the latest PayPal SDK, which seems to turn off TLS v1.0 support in the .NET app (in a way that affects other SDKs).  I have raised it on the AWS SES forum, which I hope is a good place to ask and get an official answer from AWS. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221748

Comment: @AcidPAT have you found a solution to this?  I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @AcidPAT I'm also having the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, i still have not. if you follow Chris' link on the forums (http://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=221748) it suggests that there IS no solution.
The next thing that I was going to try was to disable 1.0 only on inbound but I have not given it a shot yet.

Comment: I think that this may be a workaround. What we have done is to disable "server" tls but leave "client" TLS enabled.

Comment: This should help disable TLS 1.0 for Amazon SES. https://www.chowles.com/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-on-aws/
I was having an issue with this as well, and I enabled TLS 1.0 for Client, which worked for now, but I want to disable TLS 1.0 permanently.

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question:
We left TLS 1.0 Client enabled, and TLS 1.0 SERVER disabled.  This made SSLLabs and PCI checks happy, while still allowing us to connect to Amazon SES to send Email.  Here is the code that we use:

```
    private static Tuple<string, string, bool>[] s_ProtocolConfig = 
    {
        Tuple.Create("SSL 2.0", "client", false),
        Tuple.Create("SSL 2.0", "server", false),
        Tuple.Create("SSL 3.0", "client", false),
        Tuple.Create("SSL 3.0", "server", false),
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.0", "client", true),    // Leave this to TRUE, so that we can send outgoing email.
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.0", "server", false),   // Change this to disable incoming 1.0 TLS requests
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.1", "client", true),
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.1", "server", true),
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.2", "client", true),
        Tuple.Create("TLS 1.2", "server", true),
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Disable/Enable Protocole
    /// require a reboot if the values are changed.
    /// </summary>
    private static bool ConfigureProtocols(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, string, bool>> config)
    {
        bool rebootRequired = false;
        using (RegistryKey protocols = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols", true))
        {
            foreach (Tuple<string, string, bool> proto in config)
            {
                string protocol = proto.Item1;
                string clientServer = proto.Item2;
                bool enabled = proto.Item3;

                using (RegistryKey group = protocols.CreateSubKey(protocol))
                {
                    bool added = group.OpenSubKey(clientServer) == null;

                    using (RegistryKey newKey = group.CreateSubKey(clientServer))
                    {
                        bool updated = EnsureValue(newKey, "disabledbydefault", !enabled);
                        updated |= EnsureValue(newKey, "enabled", enabled);
                        newKey.Close();

                        if (!added && updated)
                        {
                            // the values have changed. Reboot is required to have them be reflected
                            rebootRequired = true;
                        }
                        if (added && !enabled)
                        {
                            // lack of added key is the same as enabled.
                            // therefore was enabled, but we need disabled = reboot required
                            rebootRequired = true;
                        }
                    }
                    group.Close();
                }
            }
            protocols.Close();
        }
        return rebootRequired;
    }

    private static bool EnsureValue(RegistryKey key, string name, bool value)
    {
        object currentValue = key.GetValue(name);
        object expectedValue = value ? 1 : 0;
        if (currentValue == null || !object.Equals(currentValue, expectedValue))
        {
            key.SetValue(name, expectedValue);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I am late to the party, I know, but I just disabled TLS 1.0 for PCI compliance reasons as well, and ran into this issue while trying to send emails with SES. I have enabled TLS 1.0 for client, but I will probably permanently disable by disabling TLS 1.0 in Amazon using this page: https://www.chowles.com/how-to-disable-tls-1-0-on-aws/